# \[MediaRemote\] Error Operation requires a client callback to have been registered. requesting playback queue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently learning Swift and I am creating an app for a webradio.

I get an error when calling this code :

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: currentTrack.artist,
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: currentTrack.title,
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArtwork,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: 1.0,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType: 1.0,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex: 0,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount: 0
]
```

Here's the error :

> [MediaRemote] Error Operation requires a client callback to have been
>   registered. requesting playback queue

Does anyone knows why? I'm French so I don't correctly understand this error but what I can understand is that something could be missing? If yes, what?

Thanks to all for helping!

Comment: same here. no clue what it is

Comment: Happening to me as well.  When I first start streaming music with my app and send it into the background and then lock the device the lock screen meta data does not exist.  But if I start streaming and simply lock the screen (not placing app in background) then the lock screen meta data does exist and will continue to be updated even if I place the app in the background at a later time.

Comment: I think I know what is going on.  I am setting the meta data using MPNowPlayingInfoCenter before the audio has started playing.  My app gets the meta data from the stream itself (Icecast) so I know data has started to come in off the network, but the app attempts to update the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter with this data before the first buffer has been filled (i.e. before the music starts playing).  Therefore I believe that the audio player is not completely initialized yet (i.e. the client callback has not been *fully* registered yet).  Hence the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I opened a Technical Support Incident with Apple's developer teams and they replied to me :

> Hello Didier,
>
> The engineering team came back and said that the fact
>   you are seeing those log messages is actually a bug in the system
>   framework and do not mean you are incorrectly using the
>   MPNowPlayingInfoCenter API. You should use the [MPRemoteCommandSample
>   sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MPRemoteCommandSample/Introduction/Intro.html) as a reference when updating your application as
>   it highlights the engineering recommended best practices when using
>   the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter APIs.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Developer Technical Support
>   Apple Worldwide Developer Relations